# Pre-recorded video will not open using the VideoCapture class in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I have been unable to open a video using the VideoCapture class in the python cv2 module.  I have a video called handShake_0001.avi in the directory in which I am running my python script.  Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('handShake_0001.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've been looking for the python source for cv2, but all I can find in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is a .so file for cv2 (cv2.so).  I've noticed in the documentation that VideoCapture can take either an integer (corresponding to the index for a camera) or a filename as inputs to its constructor.  When I pass in an integer to VideoCapture, I can view images using my laptop's computer (although I cannot get videos of these images to save to disk).  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Below is my build information regarding Video I/O (the result of cv2.getBuildInformation():

```
Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
    codec:                     NO
    format:                    NO
    util:                      NO
    swscale:                   NO
    gentoo-style:              NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code. successful decoding of video depends on codecs installed, your box might just not have it. ( and again, unfortunately, 'avi' is just a container, there might be almost anything hidden in it)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Any tips on installing the proper codes/drivers?

Comment: sorry for the bad news, but that's going to be a painful ride. try to open the vid with another program, like vlc, query all info you can get from there about the codec used, try something like [fourcc](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) to acquire the missing parts

Comment: @berak thank you very much!  I'm viewing the video through vlc, and everything plays just fine.  It says that the MPEG-4 Video (XVID) codec is being used to process the video.  Given that the codec appears to be installed, could it be that opencv is referencing an outdated/incorrect version/codec when processing the video feed?

Comment: yea, might be as well true. again, i got no idea, if your python module was compiled using gstreamer or ffmpeg (cv2.getBuildInformation()). sadly also, i can't help much from here on

Comment: So I just uploaded the output from cv2.getBuildInformation() concerning video i/o.  Would you recommend re-compiling my code using the appropriate ffmpeg and/or gstreamer flags?

Comment: though being more a windows guy, thus far out of my comfort zone, i'd say - yes. it seems you got neither ffmpeg nor gstreamer, so what on earth would be used to decompress your video ? . you'd probably need to install (?dev packages) of the one or the other first, then recompile opencv